Trying to make a post and get failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException
I'm trying to create this post that takes a therapist and assign him a speciality:
    @Transactional
    @PostMapping("/crear")
    public Terapeuta crearTerapeuta(@RequestBody TerapeutaRequest terapeutaRequest) {
        // Aquí puedes acceder a los datos del terapeuta y la especialidad
        Terapeuta terapeuta = terapeutaRequest.getTerapeuta();
        Long especialidadId = terapeutaRequest.getEspecialidadId();
        
        // Agregar la lógica para crear el terapeuta y agregar la especialidad
        return terapeutaService.crearTerapeutaConEspecialidad(terapeuta, especialidadId);
    }

But when I do on Postman http://localhost:8080/terapeuta/crear with this body:
{
    "terapeuta": {
        "nombre": "John",
        "apellido": "Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@example.com",
        "phone": "1234567890",
        "password": "securepassword",
        "license": "ABCD1234"
    },
    "especialidadId": 1
}

I get this error:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-06-08T12:27:02.154+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:213)\r\n\tat
ETC...
ETC...
org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)\r\n",
    "message": "Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported.",
    "path": "/terapeuta/crear"
}

And this in my springboot console log:
m.c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.demo.model.TerapeutaRequest]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'terapeutaPacientesAtendidos': no back reference property found from type `java.util.List<com.example.demo.model.TerapeutaPaciente>`
GestionTerapias m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]

I did verified that my Postman is set as Content/Type application/json. When trying to debug get error before being in the first line of the controller function:
I paste the rest of the logic:
Terapeuta.java
package com.example.demo.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("terapeuta")
@Entity
@Table(name = "Terapeuta")
public class Terapeuta extends User{
    private String license;
    
    @JsonManagedReference(value="terapeutaPacientesAtendidos")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "terapeuta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TerapeutaPaciente> pacientesAtendidos;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "terapeuta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<TerapeutaEspecialidad> especialidades = new HashSet<>();

    public Terapeuta(String nombre, String apellido, String email, String phone, String password, String license) {
        super(nombre, apellido, email, phone, password);
        this.license = license;
        this.pacientesAtendidos = new ArrayList<>();
        this.especialidades = new HashSet<>(); 
    }

    public void agregarEspecialidad(TerapeutaEspecialidad terapeutaEspecialidad) {
        especialidades.add(terapeutaEspecialidad);
        terapeutaEspecialidad.setTerapeuta(this);
    }
    
    public void setPacientesAtendidos(List<TerapeutaPaciente> pacientesAtendidos) {
        this.pacientesAtendidos = pacientesAtendidos;
    }
}

Especialidad.java
package com.example.demo.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Especialidad")
public class Especialidad {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nombre;

}

TerapeutaEspecialidad.java
package com.example.demo.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties("especialidad")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "TerapeutaEspecialidad")
public class TerapeutaEspecialidad {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference(value="terapeutasEspecialidad")
    @JoinColumn(name = "terapeuta_id")
    private Terapeuta terapeuta;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "especialidad_id")
    private Especialidad especialidad;
    
    public void setTerapeuta(Terapeuta terapeuta) {
        this.terapeuta = terapeuta;
    }
    
    public TerapeutaEspecialidad(Terapeuta terapeuta, Especialidad especialidad) {
        this.terapeuta = terapeuta;
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
    }

}

TerapeutaRequest.java
package com.example.demo.model;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TerapeutaRequest {
    private Terapeuta terapeuta;
    private Long especialidadId;
}


And also my ddbb configuration.
gestionterapias
I did verified that postman is set correctly. Changed @JsonManagedReference(value="terapeutaPacientesAtendidos") or deleted it to see but gives a 500 error, reviewed the db configuration and setup and changed the post mapping and tried to use @JsonIdentityInfo.
My github repository to get a complete view: https://github.com/LuceroAlondra/GestionTerapias
Edit:
Also when I remove @JsonBackReference(value="terapeutasEspecialidad") I get a 500 Java.lang.StackOverflowError

The error is about TerapeutaRequest. Please supply it's code

What is better - create and send us minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example As the error is in web layer try leave controller only in very simple form. Also supply Java version, build system version, build system file and instructions how build and run the example

the problem comes from trying to use JPA Entities in Controller. Create and use DTO classes instead (which u can then map into an entity once you received it in controller). Also in DTO class only define the fields you actually are sending.
